# Is dividing latency by frequency an accurate way to compare RAM

Tags: memory, performance, latency

I want to buy some RAM, and there are lots of variations in latency and frequency.

Of course, less latency is better, and more frequency is better.

The problem is comparing two memories when one has both more latency and more frequency.

I searched online and couldn't find any consensus. But one webpage said that the proper way is dividing the latency by the frequency, and the best memory is the one with a smaller result.

According to that theory, some DDR4 memories I found on sale could be sorted from better to worse:

1. CL14 3200 MHz (4.37‰)
2. CL15 3200 MHz (4.68‰)
3. CL12 2400 MHz (5.00‰)
   CL15 3000 MHz (5.00‰)
   CL16 3200 MHz (5.00‰)
4. CL13 2133 MHz (6.09‰)
5. CL15 2400 MHz (6.25‰)
6. CL14 2133 MHz (6.56‰)
   CL15 2666 MHz (6.56‰)
7. CL16 2400 MHz (6.66‰)

Is this reliable?

My processor says it doesn't support more than 2133 MHz, but it works if I enable XMP. Does this matter, e.g. maybe I won't get the full performance expected by this division if I greatly exceed 2133 MHz?

Comment: "My processor says it doesn't support more than 2133 MHz," -Your processor indicates the speed at which it supports that does not involve any overclocking.  You should look to your motherboard for memory compatability

Comment: @Ramhound It says it supports until DDR4 3400. There is a single qualified vendor with that frequency, but I guess other vendors would also work?

Comment: DDR4 memory is DDR4.memory.  Check the motherboard for any compatibility requirements with regards to the memory.  You will see virtual no increase/decrease in performance given a specific frequency.  a CL16 vs CL12 at 3200 MHz will virtually run exactly the same.  You will only see the difference in a benchmark which IS NOT an accurate representation of the real performance of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an interesting blog post that explores the latency vs speed question: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/memory-performance-speed-latency.

This article's conclusion:

> Which is more important: speed or latency?
>
> Based on in-depth engineering analysis and extensive testing in the Crucial Performance Lab, the answer to this classic question is **speed**. In general, as speeds have increased, true latencies have remained approximately the same, meaning faster speeds enable you to achieve a higher level of performance. True latencies haven't necessarily increased, just CAS latencies. And CL ratings are an inaccurate, and often misleading, indicator of true latency (and memory) performance.

I agree with this conclusion. If you're actually using programs that use a lot of memory, then your system is likely moving a lot of information in and out of RAM, and your memory controller should be intelligently scheduling these transfers to maximize throughput and minimize latency.

I think the latency / speed equation is interesting from an academic perspective, but it is missing the larger point: CAS latency only affects you when the memory has to activate a new column, while speed is *always* a factor. The scheduler in the memory controller can optimize accesses to activate columns in an optimal order to minimize latency, such as scheduling concurrent accesses from different banks so data from one bank is being read out during the CAS delay from another bank. But the controller can't do anything to increase *speed*.

**TL;DR**
No, latency/speed is not very useful for evaluating RAM quality. Don't worry about the latency. Go for speed.

Comment: That article says `trueLatency = clockCycleTime x numberOfClockCycles`. Since `clockCycleTime` is proportional to the inverse of the frequency and `numberOfClockCycles` is the CL, that basically means that `CL / frequency` is right?

Comment: @Oriol Yes, your math is correct. But the math doesn't assign any weight to either of those values. Speed is more important than latency (up to a limit, of course). To make these calculations more meaningful, the speed should be weighted more heavily. If you have two RAM options with equal speed and different latency values, certainly choose the one with less latency. In any other reasonable case though, speed should be chosen, even if `CL/f` is higher.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, `CL/f` is the proper way to calculate the real latency, but when determining which RAM is better both the frequency and the real latency matter.

Comment: Yup. And the frequency matters *more* than the latency, because the memory controller can often hide the effects of the latency but can't increase the frequency.